# Prepared Statement and Statement/Query Caching

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, query-cache

I am trying to understanding if Statement caching is useful in case of parametrized prepared statements.

As per my understanding

- If I use caching,  then query will cached based on its 'String'.
- In this case, if a query has different values of parameter then it is a different / new statement/string w.r.t. caching.
- Also, when parameters change, the results also  change.
- Since prepared statements are parameterized, is it really useful to use caching in this case.

I am using JDBC/Snaq DB Pool/ MySQL database.

Statement Caching here is referred to two different cases:

- JAVA: Snaq DB pool provided ConnectionCache class which facilitates caching of Statements.
- MySQL: DB also provided ways to cache query and result.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

My confusion is simple:

- If I were to search a Query / Corresponding Result in a Cache, I will search it on basis of String comparison.
- If parameter values change, so does String of query.
- This will result in to different entries in cache for same query with different set of values of parameters.

Hope I clarify my question.

Comment: What particular language and/or database you are talking about? What is "statement cache"?

Comment: Updated my question. Hope it is more clear.

Comment: You'd better updated your *tags*

Comment: Added tags as well. \

Comment: why down vote ? whats wrong ?

Comment: simple Google search finds this as the very first result: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/stmtcach.htm

Comment: May be I am not correct about JDBC, but what about Select query/result caching done by mysql. I have clearly mentioned TWO cases in question

Answer (score 5):

#### Statement caching is about caching the execution plan

`JDBC` query caching is done on the database side of things and it caches the `execution plan`, what the values of the parameters are is of no consequence, only that they are in the same order every time. If the values actually mattered there would be no point in caching anything.

Long time ago you had to use `PreparedStatements` to get execution plans to be cached, but since about 2005 - 2008 all the modern databases worth mentioning cache execution plans regardless of the type of statement that is executed.

There is some minimal client side caching of the actual Java Object that represents the `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement` but any actual savings in time or space will be minimal in a modern `JDBC` driver.

The overhead of calculating the `execution plan` on the server side is orders of magnitude larger than doing to simple `String` manipulation on the client side. This means there is no *meaningful* performance benefit on the client side of using a `PreparedStatement`, there are other more important benefits like `SQL Injection` protection to justify using one.

Comment: you are implying that there is no benefit of using PreparedStatement now.

Comment: not implying, saying that directly, in the case of saving time or space, `PreparedStatements` don't give you any benefit now like they originally did 15 years ago. They have other much more important benefits.

Comment: PreparedStatement protect against SQL injection attacks, they perform better with JDBC batching and the increase the chance of reusing a cached Execution Plan. Only Oracle and SQL Server provide forced Statement parametrization, but that also has downsides too.

Comment: Is there a source for this claim that PreparedStatements are not useful anymore? Or any type of a more in depth article about this topic? I would be particularly interested in knowing more about it for Postgres.